# Using classes and main programs together in Java

Tags: java, class, program-entry-point

Hey guys I'm stressing over something that's probably really simple. Basically I'm in the middle of a project that  requires me to make a frame with JRadioButtons, and do certain tasks depending on what the user clicks. Below I have my main method in the first file:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Project2_ScottHoganChanged
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JFrame main_frame = new JFrame("Welcome to Murratime Limited Cruise Lines"); //Sets a title for the JFrame
    main_frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //Closes the JFrame when exiting

    Cabin_ChoiceChanged choice = new Cabin_ChoiceChanged("", ""); //Calls upon the constructor of my Cabin_Choice class
    main_frame.getContentPane().add(choice); //Places choice into the current JFrame pane

    main_frame.pack(); //Sizes the frame
    main_frame.setVisible(true); //Allows us to see the frame

  } //Ends the main method
} //Ends the class
```

And here is my current code for my class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cabin_ChoiceChanged extends JPanel
{
  final private JLabel description;
  final private JRadioButton cabin1;
  String answer1, passFname1, passFname2, passLname1, passLname2;
  int passnum;
  boolean run=true;
  boolean passengerx1;
  boolean passengerx2;
  Scanner scan_in = new Scanner(System.in);


  public Cabin_ChoiceChanged(String passfname, String passlname) //This is the constructor for the Cabin_Choice class
  {
    description = new JLabel("Choose your Cabin or Suite"); //Creates the label
    description.setFont(new Font("Helonia", Font.BOLD, 28)); //Changes text font and formats for the description

    //Creates Radio Buttons for the frame.
    cabin1 = new JRadioButton("Cabin 11-1");

    //Changes foreground AKA the text.
    cabin1.setForeground(Color.white);

    //Changes the background of the radio button
    cabin1.setBackground(new Color(31, 21, 202)); //Creates my own custom background color

//Adds the buttons to a group so only one can be selected at a time
ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
group.add(cabin1);

//Creates a new listener so we can recognize that the user clicks on certain radio buttons
Cabin_Listener cabinlisten = new Cabin_Listener();
cabin1.addActionListener(cabinlisten);

add(description);
add(cabin1);

//Sets the background for the entire frame
setBackground(Color.white);
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000)); //Sets the default size of the frame
  }
//The following class implements the ActionListener and will
//will change the color of the radio buttons depending on what
//the user clicks on. It also makes use of if else statements.

private class Cabin_Listener implements ActionListener
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
  {
    Object source = event.getSource();
    if (source == cabin1) //If the user clicks the Cabin 1 radio button, this statement will run
    {//Beginning of the above if statement
      cabin1.setBackground(new Color(24, 204, 224)); //Sets the background for the selected cabin
      System.out.println("You have selected Cabin 11-1. Would you like to book this cabin? Y/N");

      answer1=scan_in.nextLine();
      answer1=answer1.toLowerCase();

      //This creates a nested if statement if they choose yes
      if(answer1.equals("yes") || answer1.equals("y"))
      {//Begins the command of the nested if statement
        System.out.println("Please provide us with the following information so we can finish your reservation for Cabin 1:");
        System.out.println("How many passengers will be in this cabin? *Note: The maximum number of passengers in a cabin is 2*");
        passnum=scan_in.nextInt();
        scan_in.nextLine(); //I had to put this here because the scan_in.nextInt() messes with the next scan_in.nextLine(), so this line truly ends the scan_in.nextInt()

        while(run==true)
        {//Opens the while(run==true) loop
        switch (passnum)
        {//Switch (passnum) opening bracket
          case 1:
            System.out.println("You have 1 passenger in this cabin. You will be charged an extra 45% onto your bill because the cabin isn't fulfilled.");
            run=false; //Won't repeat the loop
            passengerx1=true; //For use later to determine information about the passenger
            break;
          case 2:
            System.out.println("You have 2 passengers in this cabin");
            run=false; //Won't repeat the loop
            passengerx2=true; //For use later to determine information about the passengers
            break;
          default:
            System.out.println("You entered a number of passengers that isn't allowed.");
            System.out.println("How many passengers will be in this cabin?");
            passnum=scan_in.nextInt(); //Will ask for user input on passenger number again to prevent an infinite loop
            run=true; //This will cause the loop to repeat

        }//Switch (passnum) closing bracket
        }//Closes the while(run==true) loop
        if(passengerx1=true) //The statement inside here will recieve the passenger's first and last name as well as information about their city, state, dining time, and excursions
        {//Opens the if(passengerx1=true) statement
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println("Please enter the passenger's first name: ");
          passFname1=scan_in.nextLine();
          System.out.println("Please enter the passenger's last name: ");
          passLname1=scan_in.nextLine();
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println("Thank you "+passFname1+" "+passLname1+".");

        }//Closes the if(passengerx1=true) statement
      }//Closes the first nested if statement
    }//Ends the main if statement
  }
}
}
```

The program itself works, but one big thing my teacher is requiring us to do is create 6 total methods in my class and use them in my main program. I must also create objects in my main and edit them using methods from my class. When I run the program it all works well, but I don't understand how I can make methods inside my class and use them in my main program. All I know so far is that when I call for a method it will do what's inside that method, but say for example one of the passenger objects that I create needs something changed, how do I tell my main program to wait until that passenger object that I created is finished scanning in stuff from my class?

I guess the easiest way would to be to make an *if* or *while* statement inside my main program to run what's inside only if the scanning in from the class is finished? But how would my main program know when the scanning in is finished?

-EDIT-

I have some Scanners inside the class and I want to get information from the Scanner and then use and manipulate that information inside my main program after the user has finished inputting all the data

Comment: I suggest you set some breakpoints in main and in a few of the methods of the class so you can see what's happening with the flow of the code.

Comment: If your code is swing-based, then it's (or should be) all running on a single thread, so your event handler code gets called one-at-a-time.  If this is the case, you don't have to wait for other code to "finish", it already has.